# AssertJ - The method isEqualToComparingFieldByFieldRecursively don't work with RuntimeException object

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, assertj

#### Summary

The method isEqualToComparingFieldByFieldRecursively don't work with RuntimeException object. The check always return true even if we change the RuntimeException message in the expected RuntimeException.

#### Not working example (always true)

```
assertThat(caughtException).as("The Runtime exception")
            .usingComparatorForType(ComparatorCollection.getDateComparator(MAX_ALLOWABLE_SEC_FOR_EQ),
                    LocalDateTime.class)
            .usingComparatorForType(ComparatorCollection.getXmlDateComparator(MAX_ALLOWABLE_SEC_FOR_EQ),
                    XMLGregorianCalendar.class)
            .isEqualToComparingFieldByFieldRecursively(expectedResults));
            // caughtException.message and expectedResults.message are different but return true
```

#### Working example

```
assertThat(caughtException).as("The Runtime exception")
            .usingComparatorForType(ComparatorCollection.getDateComparator(MAX_ALLOWABLE_SEC_FOR_EQ),
                    LocalDateTime.class)
            .usingComparatorForType(ComparatorCollection.getXmlDateComparator(MAX_ALLOWABLE_SEC_FOR_EQ),
                    XMLGregorianCalendar.class)
            .isEqualToComparingFieldByFieldRecursively(expectedResults)
            // The recursively check don't work with the RuntimeException message
            .isEqualToComparingOnlyGivenFields(expectedResults, "message");
```

We have make some tests and the second example work (when we force the check of the attribut message).

Comment: looks like a bug, report it on their github page

Comment: also paste all all other code, the source of the exception classes

Comment: and the source or library of ComparatorCollection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old limitation of the code retrieving the fields to compare which ignored any type in `java.lang` (to avoid comparing `Object` field by field).

This is too drastic and needs to be loosen, this bug has been created to track the issue https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core/issues/1224.